# Rubymine debugging

Tags: debugging, rubymine

I have Installed

- 2017.1.5 Version of Ruby
- ruby-2.4.1-p111

I've made a new project and named it hello.rb. When I run it, everything works fine. However when I try to debug the project I get a prompt message
[The gem debase required by the debugger is not currently installed. Would you like to install?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6O0Z.png)

[Error running hello. Following gems were not installed:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDRWG.png)

I've tried re-installing everything and restarting and I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: `gem install debase`?

Answer (score 1):

Well apparently debugger in RubyMine does require this gem. So You have multiple ways of doing this.
Assuming your File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Ruby SDK and Gems
contains only one ruby version and its the selected one (and the gem really isn't in the list). As halfelf said in your terminal/cmd/iterm you would simply write

```
gem install debase
```

Also you could create file called Gemfile that would have all the gems in

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'debase'
```

and in the future any other gems you would need, Rubymine should be able to install those for you.

If you would have already installed the gem, there might be a gem installation conflict that would need to be resolved.